# R- FactoMiner MCA How to select Important Features?

Tags: r, pca

My dataset is a mixture of Numeric, and  categorical Values, Outcome is a Class Label, there are around 400 columns  and the dataset contains missing values. There are many Questions in my mind. First is :

1. How to deal with missing Values ? I replaced all missing values with -1, is it okay ??
2. How to apply MCA Factor analysis on this data  ? Shall I combine train and test then apply MCA ?
3. How to interpret output of MCA Analysis to get most relevant features ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not touch your dataset
   If you use FactoMineR package it handle missing Values itself.
2. You have to try this kind of code

   ```
   library(FactoMineR)
   library(factoextra)

   df <- data.frame(df) # Dataset with only categorical variables
   res.mca <- MCA(df, quali.sup)

   # Visualize Principal Components
   fviz_eig(res.mca, 
            addlabels = TRUE)

   # Individual plot
   fviz_mca_ind(res.mca, 
                col.ind = "cos2",
                axes = c(1,2), # axes by default
                repel = TRUE)

    # Variable plot on axe 1
    fviz_contrib(res.mca, 
                 choice = "var", 
                 axes = 1, # you can switch with the other axes
                 top = 10)

    # Best variable contribution
    fviz_mca_var(res.mca, col.var = "contrib",
                 axes = c(1,2),
                repel = TRUE)
   ```
3. Interpretation looks like PCA.

   - Visualize Principal Components (CP) : see %information of each variables
   - Individual & Variable plots : bring out correlations variables and outliers
   - Contribution : see %variable contribution on each axes